# About: error C2065: "KINECT_LOCKED_RECT" undeclared identifier

Tags: kinect

Have anyone seen the problem? 
my header files:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <NuiApi.h>
#include <NuiImageCamera.h>
```

include is ok
kinect version: beta 1.0

Answer (score 0):

It was renamed to `NUI_LOCKED_RECT`.